# Inc sql query validation

Tags: sql

I was given a table with 4 fields:

```
[record_id] is the pk
[pay_serial_number] should always be increased +1
[worker_id] each worker has unique id
[content] just some content.
```

I am being told that the adding function had a bug and jumped on many serial numbers.
I need to create a query to print for each worker the missing serial numbers.

```
[worker_id][missing serial number]
[worker_id][missing serial number]
[worker_id][missing serial number]
```

What is the most fast and efficient method to print such table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the "missing" serial numbers is kind of hard.  They are not in the data, so you would have to generate them.

However, it is not too hard to find the missing ranges.  For this use a correlated subquery to get the next serial number (or use the `lead()` or `lag()` function if available).  Then find any where there are gaps.

Here is the query:

```
select worker_id, pay_serial_number + 1 as FirstMissing,
       (nextpsn - pay_serial_number - 1) as NumMissing
from (select t.*,
             (select min(pay_serial_number)
              from t_workers_pay t2
              where t2.worker_id = t.worker_id and -- ASSUMING SEQUENTIAL FOR A WORKER
                    t2.pay_serial_number > t.pay_serial_number
             ) as nextpsn
      from t_workers_pay t
     ) t
where nextpsn - pay_serial_number > 1;
```

Comment: what is t and what is t2?

Comment: @user1021182 . . . `t` is both the name of your table and a table alias.  `t2` is a table alias.

Comment: i cant make this query work , i replaced all the t with the name of my table "t_workers_pay" and its not working -Getting Incorrect syntax near 't2'

Comment: can you look on it again, i cant find the syntax mistake - the current edited version also have syntax mistake

Comment: @user1021182 . . . The current version in the answer is not working?

Comment: yes - Incorrect syntax near 't2'. im not sure but you might not using the t_workers_pay t2 correct. maybe you need to use "as". almost sure that you have not set correct syntax for t2

Comment: @user1021182 . . . You don't specify your database.  The `as` is definitely optional for table aliases.  The only exception to this rule (that I know of) is MS Access.

Comment: its not related to db, the table is exactly how i described it - there is a syntax error in your code

Comment: @user1021182 . . . The code runs just fine as written, as you can see at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ca1b/1.

Comment: I was referring MS SQL 2008

Comment: @user1021182 . . . This code is pretty generic.  It should work in SQL Server as well.